# Suppress Warning "Unable to automatically debug 'ServiceName' The remote procedure could not be debugged"

Tags: asp.net, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I get the warning "Unable to automatically debug 'ServiceName'. The remote procedure could not be debugged..." when I run my ASP.NET MVC application and my services are hit the first time.

Unlike many others who I get this warning, I can actually debug my service if I attach to the IISexpress process, but I get this warning once for every service but time it's called and it's somewhat of an annoynce since we have a handfull of services.

I would really like to get rid of this warning, since it doesn't even apply and is just in the way. Everything I have found in my search is people who can't debug their service and are missing the right setting.

Additional info:
- ASP.NET MVC application calling WCF services exposed through https and webhttpbinding
Projects for both MVC app and service projects are in the same solution
- debug=true is set in both client and server web.config, though from what I can read it should only be needed in the client
- Warning seen by all developers on the team running Visual Studio 2012 (update 4), but not thoose running 2010
- Visual Studio have been repaired as suggested on a Microsoft help page linked to in the warning - no change.
- Services hosted in IIS Express
- Project target is x86 (x64 fails completely)
- If services are exposed as pure http, not https, the warning goes away, but thats not really a viable solution

First stackoverflow post - so be gentle. :-)